# How to make header in css but im using opacity?

Tags: css

im making header for html. and this is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: yellow
        }
        .atas{
            background-color: red;
            width: 700px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            top:0px;
            height: 190px;
            position: fixed;
            left:200px;         
        }
        .one{
            background-color: bisque;
           border-radius: 50px;
            width:125px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: 50px;
           position: static;
        }
        .two{  
             background-color: bisque;
           border-radius: 50px;
            width:125px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
           position: static;
        }
        .three{

            background-color: bisque;
           border-radius: 50px;
            width:125px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            position: static;
        }
        .upermain{
             opacity: 0.9;
            background-color: black;
            top:200px;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            left: 0px;
        }
        .article{
            opacity: 0.7;
            background-color: lightgray;
            width:100%;
            height:500px;
            top:280px;
            position: relative;
            left: 0px;

        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><div class="atas"><div class="one"><br/><font style="arial" color="green">HOME</font></div>
    <div class="two"><font style="arial" color="green"><br/>Contact</font></div>
    <div class="three"><font style="arial" color="green"><br/>Article</font></div>
   </div> <div class="upermain"><h1>Articles</h1></div>
   <div class="article">Text <br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/> 
   </div> 
    </body>
```

how to make the black background under the red background when scrolling?
im using opacity.if i delete the opacity it will become what i want.but i need the opacity
and how to make home contact and article to margin to the right?
here's the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mhFxf/5015/
thanks before!

Comment: I'm not getting what you need? You could set the background color to something like this: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need z-index in css.
The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```css
 <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color: yellow
            }
            .atas{
                background-color: red;
                width: 700px;
                border-radius: 50px;
                top:0px;
                height: 190px;
                position: fixed;
                left:200px;  
                z-index:99;
            }
            .one{
                background-color: bisque; 
               border-radius: 50px;
                width:125px;
                height: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-left: 50px;
               position: static;
            }
            .two{  
                 background-color: bisque;
               border-radius: 50px;
                width:125px;
                height: 50px;
                text-align: center;
               position: static;
            }
            .three{
                 
                background-color: bisque;
               border-radius: 50px;
                width:125px;
                height: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                position: static;
            }
            .upermain{
                 opacity: 0.9;
                background-color: lightblue;
                top:200px;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                left: 0px;
            }
            .article{
                opacity: 0.7;
                background-color: lightgray;
                width:100%;
                height:500px;
                top:280px;
                position: relative;
                left: 0px;
                
            }
            

        </style>
```

```html
  
    
    <body>
        <div><div class="atas"><div class="one"><br/><font style="arial" color="green">HOME</font></div>
        <div class="two"><font style="arial" color="green"><br/>Contact</font></div>
        <div class="three"><font style="arial" color="green"><br/>Article</font></div>
       </div> <div class="upermain"><h1>Articles</h1></div>
       <div class="article">Text <br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/>text<br/> 
     </div>
```